# How is networking implemented in the Boost Library

Tags: c++, networking, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

How is networking in the `Boost Library` implemented? More specifically, how is the `asio` library implemented?

As far as I know, you can download the boost library and use it in your C++ programs (also it's portable) on any machine that supports C++ compilation. Does this mean it is written in pure C++? If it is I can't see how. How do you implement networking in pure C++?

If it is not written in pure C++, then how is it implemented? How is it portable?

**TLDR;** Is the asio (networking) library in boost written in pure C++? How? If not how is it portable?

Comment: If it can't be written in C++, then it can't be written. Long note: Different platforms provide different utilities that deal with networking, most of which is written in C and C++ references to it.

Comment: Why don't you just download the source code of the boost libraries and check for yourself? But you almost have the answer already: It cannot be pure C++, it is written using OS-specific C functions. It is portable because the OS is checked when you compile the source code, and then the appropriate modules/functions are called.

Comment: @Rene I tried taking a look, but I could not find the part where it showed how networking was implemented. So many headers. Can you give a keyword to search for or a header to look in to see the implementation (Linux)? Also, thanks! I forgot you could use preprocessors.

Comment: @6EQUJ5 For example: `boost/asio/detail` contains `posix_thread.hpp` and `win_thread.hpp`. `boost/asio/detail/thread.hpp` checks the existing defines to determine, which of these files to include. Most of the OS specific stuff seems to be there.

Comment: `portable` does not mean "not using platform specific features", it means "providing the same abstractions for user regardless of platform".

Comment: @Rene Ok, now I'm getting somewhere. But, in those files there are still so many abstractions (classes). I'm having a hard time finding the actual implementation of networking (the code that calls OS-specific functions). Can you tell me the "base" class? Like, in the C++ standard library `std::ios_base` is the base class which streams inherit from. I assume the OS-specific implementation must be in the base class. Meanwhile, I will try to find it... Also, I can't seem to find the function definitions for the ones declared (not defined though)...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to find out. If you know low level networking interfaces like `select`, `bind`, `socket`, etc. then you should know what to look for. If you don't know low level interfaces and trying to learn them by looking at Boost.Asio implementation then you're doing the wrong thing. In this case I suggest a good book or article on networking. In any case, IMHO, your question is too broad and inconclusive.

Comment: @AndreySemashev I just want to see what kinds of OS-specific functions are being used. I'm not trying to understand networking. Just curious and wanted to take a look.

Comment: @6EQUJ5 Well, if you just want to understand networking, then I would look at something less complex than Boost. For example, read the 'bible' about network programming: "UNIX Network Programming" by Richard Stevens.

Comment: @Rene I said, "`I just want to see what kinds of OS-specific functions are being used. I'm not trying to understand networking. Just curious and wanted to take a look.`".

Comment: @6EQUJ5 Well, the book provides a lot source code examples, so there you would see which functions are normally used. IMHO still the better approach than studying something as sophisticated as Boost.Asio.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple description of *how* `asio` is implemented, see [CppCon 2016: Michael Caisse "Asynchronous IO with Boost.Asio"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwOv_tw2eA4&t=2009s)